# Simplify solution for Symbolic solver for system of equations in Python (with symbolic output)

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, equation-solving

I have the following system of equations :

```
-2yz = a
-2xy = b
-x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = c
```

How can I simplify the solution for these equations using SymPy? `x, y, z` are unknowns. I have the following script:

```
from sympy import *

x, y, z = var('x y z')
a, b, c = var('a b c')

E1 = -2 * y * z - a
E2 = -2 * x * y - b
E3 = -x**2 + y ** 2 - z ** 2 - c


sols = solve([E1, E2, E3], [x, y, z])
```

The simplifies solution is not really palatable. Any idea?

Comment: you tagged `sympy` yourself..

Comment: @ Ev. Kounis I've just updated my post. In fact the answer of sympy is not readable !

Answer (score 0):

You might consider running cse over your solutions. I will let you see what the replacments are, but here is the result:

```
>>> r, e = cse(flatten(sols))
>>> reshape(e, (3,))  # restore tuples of 3 solutions
[
(x1*x9, -x11*x13, x9), 
(-x1*x13, x11*x9, -x13), 
(-x16, x12*x17, -x15), 
(x16, x17*x8, x15)]
```